# Boot process stops until PS/2 key presses?

Tags: boot, keyboard, grub, gentoo

I'm working on an embedded product based on Gentoo linux 3.6.6 running on a Mini-ITX motherboard. We're looking at switching motherboards (from a Jetway NF9D-2550 to an Advantech EIMB-214), and to test that I'm trying to boot our existing SATA development drive from the new motherboard.

When I try, the system boots through BIOS and GRUB, until I get the following two messages:

```
[0.588839] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[0.588902] EDD information not available.
```

The system then hangs and goes no further. I've done a lot of playing with BIOS settings (AHCI versus IDE, USB, SATA enable/disable, etc) and boot parameters (`edd=off`, `verbose`), to no avail.

Here's the one thing I found that helps. If I plug in a PS/2 keyboard and wait until the boot process gets to its usual hang point, then most of the time when I press a key the boot process goes a step or two further.

Each time I press a key (unless I do several too quickly) one or more new log lines appear. The timestamp on the left of each log line continues to increase rationally, e.g. if I wait ten seconds and then press a key, the new message timestamps are 10 seconds larger than the previous ones. There's some correlation between how long I wait and how many messages appear for a keypress: the longer I wait the more messages appear.

It doesn't seem to matter what key I press; even SHIFT or CAPS-LOCK works. Even pressing the external soft power button works! A USB keyboard does nothing; only a PS/2 keyboard. And, having no keyboard plugged in just hangs at the usual spot.

If I persist long enough at this, I'll get to a boot prompt, and can login, but even then things repeatedly lock up until I press a key.

Any clue what might be going wrong here?

**Edit:** With the original motherboard booting from the development SSD, and the production SATA-DOM mounted, the output of `sudo parted -l` is:

```
Model: ATA OCZ-VERTEX3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 90.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  5370MB  5369MB  primary  ext2            boot
 2      5370MB  14.0GB  8590MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 3      14.0GB  90.0GB  76.1GB  primary  ext3


Model: ATA SATADOM D150SV-L (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1011MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      512B   165MB   165MB  primary  ext3         boot
 2      165MB  1003MB  839MB  primary  ext3
```

The development SSD's `/boot/grub/grub.conf` is

```
default 0
timeout 2
#splashimage=(hd0,0)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz

title Gento Linux 3.6.6-pa
kernel /boot/kernel-3.6.6-pa root=/dev/sda3

title Gentoo Linux 3.6.6-stable7-patched
kernel /boot/kernel-3.6.6-stable7-patched root=/dev/sda1

title 3.6.6-stable7
kernel /boot/kernel-3.6.6-stable7 root=/dev/sda1

# vim:ft=conf:
```

**Edit 2:** output of `uname -a`, again on original motherboard from development SSD:

```
Linux 257platform 3.6.6-pa #2 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 2 19:41:15 EST 2014 i686 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D2700 @ 2.13GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

**Edit 3:** contents of `/boot` directory:

```
total 13168
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1641624 Mar  2  2014 System.map-3.6.6-pa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1635218 Feb  7  2013 System.map-3.6.6-stable7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1635218 Feb 13  2013 System.map-3.6.6-stable7-patched
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       1 Feb  7  2013 boot -> ./
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70513 Mar  2  2014 config-3.6.6-pa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   69921 Feb  7  2013 config-3.6.6-stable7
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar 14  2014 grub/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2789424 Mar  2  2014 kernel-3.6.6-pa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2782576 Feb  7  2013 kernel-3.6.6-stable7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2782544 Feb 13  2013 kernel-3.6.6-stable7-patched
drwx------ 2 root root   16384 Feb  4  2013 lost+found/
```

... and contents of `/boot/grub` directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    197 Feb  5  2013 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     30 Feb  5  2013 device.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8616 Feb  5  2013 e2fs_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7904 Feb  5  2013 fat_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7164 Feb  5  2013 ffs_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    680 Mar 14  2014 grub.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7180 Feb  5  2013 iso9660_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8616 Feb  5  2013 jfs_stage1_5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      9 Feb  5  2013 menu.lst -> grub.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7332 Feb  5  2013 minix_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9564 Feb  5  2013 reiserfs_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8488 Mar  7  2013 splash.xpm.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    512 Feb  5  2013 stage1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104624 Feb  5  2013 stage2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104624 Feb  5  2013 stage2_eltorito
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7432 Feb  5  2013 ufs2_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6796 Feb  5  2013 vstafs_stage1_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9264 Feb  5  2013 xfs_stage1_5
```

**Edit 4:**

I tried some of the suggestions, to no avail. The following changed nothing:

- Adding `isapnp_reserve_irq=5` to the kernel command line
- Completely resetting BIOS to default values

**Edit 5:**

One more piece of evidence: once I'm looking at a `bash` command line (on the console/VGA display), and typing commands, once in a while I'll see a burst of log messages from the kernel that look like a call trace. Omitting the timestamp info and instruction offsets, here is one:

```
kernel: Call Trace:
kernel: ? rcu_pending
kernel: ? rcu_check_callbacks
kernel: ? update_process_times
kernel: ? tick_sched_timer
kernel: ? tick_mohz_handler
kernel: ? __run_hrtimer.clone.22
kernel: ? hrtimer_interrupt
kernel: ? smp_apic_timer_interrupt
kernel: ? apic_timer_interrupt
kernel: ? calc_global_load
kernel: ? acpi_idle_enter_simple
kernel: ? cpuidle_enter
kernel: ? cpuidle_enter_state
kernel: ? cpuidle_idle_call
kernel: ? cpu_idle
kernel: Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = 299966219294 ns)
kernel: Switching to clocksource hpet
```

BTW, 299966219294 ns is just about 5 minutes.

**Edit 6:**

I've been booting from various LiveCDs. Results:

- GParted 0.14.0-1 Live x86 CD: works fine, including shell script with repetitive output
- Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.1 x386: boots, but has the same "waiting for an event" disease. Had to hit keys repeatedly during the boot process. When finished booting into Xwindows, opened terminal window, created shell script that printed out a message once a second, and ran; after each output line, had to press a key (e.g. SHIFT) to continue. Interesting thing: if I open TWO terminal windows running this script, BOTH lock up, but when I press a key BOTH step forward. After about twenty minutes running, the whole system locked up.
- Gentoo Live DVD livedvd-x86-amd64-32ul-20140826.iso, booting x86: everything worked just fine.

While in Ubuntu 12.04.1, I managed to grab some hardware reports:

```
$sudo lshw -short
H/W path               Device      Class       Description
==========================================================
                                   system      To be filled by O.E.M. (To be filled by O.E.M.)
/0                                 bus         Tiger Hill
/0/0                               memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                               processor   Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N2600   @ 1.60GHz
/0/4/5                             memory      24KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                             memory      512KiB L2 cache
/0/4/1.1                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/4/1.2                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/4/1.3                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/4/1.4                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/28                              memory      1GiB System Memory
/0/28/0                            memory      SODIMM [empty]
/0/28/1                            memory      1GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
/0/1                               processor   
/0/1/1.1                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/1/1.2                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/1/1.3                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/1/1.4                           processor   Logical CPU
/0/100                             bridge      Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller
/0/100/2                           display     Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/1b                          multimedia  N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                          bridge      N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c/0                        storage     ASM1061 SATA IDE Controller
/0/100/1c.2                        bridge      N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3
/0/100/1c.2/0          eth0        network     82574L Gigabit Network Connection
/0/100/1c.3                        bridge      N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4
/0/100/1c.3/0          eth1        network     82583V Gigabit Network Connection
/0/100/1d                          bus         N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.1                        bus         N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
/0/100/1d.2                        bus         N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
/0/100/1d.3                        bus         N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
/0/100/1d.7                        bus         N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
/0/100/1e                          bridge      82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
/0/100/1f                          bridge      NM10 Family LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2            scsi0       storage     N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD-RW DH24AS
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/0    /dev/cdrom  disk        
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/0/1              volume      695MiB Hidden HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/100/1f.3                        bus         N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller
/0/2                   scsi2       storage     
/0/2/0.0.0             /dev/sda    disk        8004MB SCSI Disk
/0/2/0.0.0/1           /dev/sda1   volume      7633MiB Windows FAT volume

$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 IDE interface: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061 SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82583V Gigabit Network Connection

$ sudo dmidecode
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
51 structures occupying 1989 bytes.
Table at 0x3F2E9010.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 4.6.5
    Release Date: 05/20/2015
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 1024 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 4.6

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Product Name: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    UUID: 03000200-0400-0500-0006-000700080009
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Family: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: INTEL Corporation
    Product Name: Tiger Hill
    Version: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 22 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU 1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: Intel            
    ID: 61 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
    Version: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N2600   @ 1.60GHz
    Voltage: 0.8 V
    External Clock: 400 MHz
    Max Speed: 1600 MHz
    Current Speed: 1600 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 1
    Thread Count: 2
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 24 kB
    Maximum Size: 24 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Other
    Installed SRAM Type: Other
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: None
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: Other

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Other
    Installed SRAM Type: Other
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: None
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 126, 19 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Centronics Type-14
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2A
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2B
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Video
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB3
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9A1 - TPM HDR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9C1 - PCIE DOCKING CONN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2B3 - CPU FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6C2 - EXT HDMI
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3C1 - GMCH FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1D1 - ITP
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E2 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E4 - MDC INTPSR
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E3 - LPC HOT DOCKING
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9E1 - SCAN MATRIX
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G1 - LPC SIDE BAND
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8F1 - UNIFIED
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6F1 - LVDS
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2F1 - LAI FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2G1 - GFX VID
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1G6 - AC JACK
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B2
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 0
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:01.0

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6D1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.4

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J7B1
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.5

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J8B4
    Type: x1 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.6

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:    To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0028
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: [Empty]
    Serial Number: [Empty]
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: [Empty]
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0028
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK 1
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MHz
    Manufacturer: Micron
    Serial Number: 22508417
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: 8JSF12864HZ-1G1D  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x002A
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x002C
    Partition Row Position: Unknown

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0028
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard LAN
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:19.0

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard 1394
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:03:1c.2

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

(I'm not supposed to say this, but thanks for all the help...)

Comment: Does this occur when booting the LiveCD, or a completed Handbook install?

Comment: It's an existing Gentoo build that we've been using on our older motherboard (a Jetway NF9D-2550). We're hoping to not have to go back to ground zero, but knowing what's failing would be critical to getting this done.

Comment: Please try this: Adding **isapnp_reserve_irq=5** to kernel command line while booting.

Comment: [long shot] Try updating the BIOS and resetting the BIOS configuration to the default, and changing only what you really need in your case.

Comment: Before you continue down a rabbit hole, please boot the new Motherboard with a LiveCD, just boot, not build, and let us know if the system completely boots.  The Hardware Detection used by the genkernel based kernel build will load the appropriate modules.  As a hunch, I have a gut feeling that your kernel is missing some driver for something on your new board.

Comment: Yes: a modern LiveCD boots fine (see details above). It's clear that there's some incompatibility between my SSD and the motherboard, and that updating everything would fix it. For various reasons, though, this would incur an enormous support expense, so I've been hoping to avoid it.

Comment: You don't need to modify the setup, just the kernel.  Use the LiveCD as a rescue CD.  Mount the boot and root, partition, copy over the networking and enter the chroot.  Back up your old kernel and emerge genkernel.  Use genkernel to build a ram disk and hardware detection.  This only adds about 15 seconds to the total boot.  Usse this as a work around until you track down the missing driver.

Comment: My guess would be this: `ASM1061 SATA IDE Controller` does not exist in your malfunctioning kernel.  You must replace the old SATA controller module with the one I have noted.  If you need these comments as a walkthrough answer let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I bet it has to do with your hard disk's heads or MBR and your problem happens a lot actually.

Because of different standards some BIOS could read from an address above the MBR which could cause your problem and what will solve that is to try using `parted` and some W.D. drives have baffling heads.

Could you post the output of `parted -l` and your grub.cfg for starters and you could read what wikipedia has to say about MBR(Master boot record) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H as that will help in the process a lot.

What is your Hard drive make and storage capacity?

Comment: This problem happens when booting from the development drive (which is a flash-based SSD), as well as from a completely separate production SATA-DOM (also flash-based). Both work fine on the previous motherboard. So, it isn't any sort of corruption with one of the drives.

Comment: then it is probably an MBR problem and this problem is much more common for linux users that use flash-based drives than normal drives

Comment: first try `parted -l` on both motherboards and i know the second one is troublesome but bare with me and please read what i asked you to read as there is a point where you will be on your own and i will just give you hints and guidelines

Comment: Info added to question, and thanks for the continuing help.

Comment: not a problem at all, could you post the /boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg ? as i fear giving you the wrong instruction for the wrong reason and causing loss of all data.

Comment: is EDD enabled or disabled?.it is supposed to help O.S. cope (as you have read in wikipedia "INT 13H") with large sector size for big size drives but as you can see your sector size is 512kb which is the standard so i guess you could turn it off as some have reported it causing issues but at the same time the two messages your bios prints when frozen indicate that it is semi-working properly and not causing issues so leaving it on will be of help too so i guess we will leave it on for now but i am just sharing my mind with you cause you might be the better judge in the end

Comment: is nolapic on? and what is your hard drive access mode?

Comment: There's no /boot/syslinux/; I've posted /boot and /boot/grub. EDD seems to be enabled (hence the messages). nolapic is not in the kernel boot line; how would I tell if it were on? hard drive mode settings in BIOS can be IDE or AHCI, it doesn't make a difference for the settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27654/discussion-between-daniel-griscom-and-user3566929).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, @user3566929. Although my problem hasn't been solved, you will be automatically awarded half the bounty when the bounty expires. Again, thanks.

Comment: @Daniel-Griscom  i don't care about the bounty and i never cared about the bounty....did you just give up or what happened?

Comment: @DanielGriscom  i don't care about the bounty and i never cared about the bounty....did you just give up or what happened?

Comment: It's the weekend, and this isn't my only task at work. I'll get back on it Tuesday. (Thanks.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom   Oh okay i will be happy to help at any time we could do it on the chatting section whenever you like

Answer (score 2):

I also have an N2600 with similar symptoms. But for me, anything after 3.16 would see this problem, but 3.16 and below was fine. I've found that acpi=off gets stuff working again.

Clearly there is some kind of issues with timers or CPU sleep states that needs to be addressed.

Comment: I recently discovered that cpuidle.off=1 is a much smaller hammer that gets this booting. In other bizzare news, 4.7 doesn't boot on this board without initcall_blacklist=inet6_init